# com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport Doesn't Exist

Tags: import, libgdx, viewport

Trying to import a viewport, more specifically a ScreenViewport, into a libgdx project project but the package doesn't seem to exist on my machine. According to the documentation and code other people have posted I'm using the right address but I'm getting an error.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
```

"The import com.badlogic.gdx.util.viewport cannot be resolved."

Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable possibility is that you are using an old version of libgdx.

Try updating jar files in your project (manually or using ui).

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: That worked, though it took me some time so figure that out. Apparently I didn't use gradle when starting the project? so I had to do it manually. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. If it has solved your problem, consider accepting the answer.